# Javascript functions only work with some "alert()" in it

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax (Javascript + php) to check if a user name is available when a user changes the focus to another field of the form. The my functions only work when I have some alert(), if I remove them, the functions stop working.

Another odd thing is that the `alert(requestObject.readyState);` only shows the state 1. As far I understand, it should show all states, or at least the state 4 as well.

This is my javascript code, it is in the header of the HTML page.

```
    var requestObject = false;
    function funcReceiveData()
    {
        alert(requestObject.readyState);
        if(requestObject.readyState == 4)
        {
            if(requestObject.status == 200)
            {
                var status = requestObject.responseText;
                if(status == "ok")
                {
                    document.getElementById('userValid').innerHTML = 'Valid user';
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('userValid').innerHTML = 'Choose another username';
                }
            }
        }
    }

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    requestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject)
{
    requestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

function checkUser()
{
    if(requestObject){
        requestObject.open("POST", "addUser.php", true);
        requestObject.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var user = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var tobesent = "username=" + user;
        requestObject.send(tobesent);
        requestObject.onreadystatechange = funcReceiveData();
        alert(tobesent);
    }
}
```

This is the body part of my HTML code:

```
<BODY>
<form method="POST" action="addUser.php">
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td><strong>Username:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" size="25" onblur="checkUser();" id="username"></td>
            <td><i id='userValid'>bla</i>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
            <td><strong>Password:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" size="25"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
            <td><strong>Frist name:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Fname" size="25"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
            <td><strong>Last name:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Lname" size="25"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
            <td><strong>Address line 1:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="address1" size="50"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
            <td><strong>Address line 2:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="address2" size="50"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
            <td><strong>City:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="city" size="25"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
            <td><strong>Postcode:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="postcode" size="25"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
            <td><strong>Phone:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="phone" size="25"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
            <td><strong>Mobile:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="mobile" size="25"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
            <td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" size="25"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            <td><input type="reset" value="Clear" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

My PHP code is below, it's a very stupid code just to test. After I'll check the user name in a database.

```
<?php 
$user = $_POST['username'];
if($user == "Tiago")
    echo("ok");
else
    echo("Error");
?>
```

I have the page hosted in this address: https://devweb2012.cis.strath.ac.uk/~ntb13105/WAD/tests/Twig/FINAL/addUser.html

Does anyone have any clue of what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

You are *calling* `funcReceiveData` instead of using it as the `readyStateChange` event handler.

It doesn't work because at that point the HTTP request hasn't had a response. Sticking an alert in it delays the attempt to read the value of `requestObject.readyState` until you click OK, which is long enough for the response to arrive.

Remove the `()` and assign the event handler before sending the request.

```
requestObject.onreadystatechange = funcReceiveData;
requestObject.send(tobesent);
```